# Selenium Web Driver for a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium, rspec, webdriver

I am trying to set up Selenium for my Rails project and I want to use chrome as my browser. It currently works as open up firefox only. [I have](http://pivotallabs.com/users/dwfrank/blog/articles/category/161-rails) `Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end` in my `spec_helper.rb` but it still opens firefox when I run specs. What am I missing?

Comment: weird, this should work: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#configuring-and-adding-drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed. Had to use `Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|` [instead of](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) `Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|`.